# Simple groups and irreducible characters of degree 3

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

I have posted this question on mathstack echange but did not get any answer. It mam trying my luck here.

The only simple finite groups admitting an irreducible character of degree 3 are $\mathfrak{A}_5$
and $PSL(2,7)$. That seems to be a result coming from Blichfeldt's work on $GL(3,\mathbb{C})$, which I cannot find. Is there a proof available somewhere ?

Comment: This is also done in Determination of the ordinary and modular ternary linear groups
    Howard H. Mitchell.
    Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 12 (1911), 207-242, but that is a long and complicate paper. Why can't you find Blichfeldt's papers? Do you not have access to Trans Amer Math Soc? It's an interesting question, because all of the modern treatments that I have found seem to cite Blichfeldt or Mitchell.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I found Mitchell's article. To answer your question, I only have access to articles freely available on the internet.

Comment: The articles of H.F. Blichfeldt in the AMS Transactions are indeed freely available on the internet: http://www.ams.org/epubsearch/servlet/PubSearch?f1=msc&v1=&co1=and&f2=title&v2=&co2=and&f3=fulltext&v3=&co3=and&f4=author&v4=blichfeldt&onepub=tran&startmo=00&startyr=&endmo=00&endyr=&sperpage=30&ssort=d&sendit22=Search

Comment: It might be worth remarking that the triple cover of $A_{6}$ ( which is not simple of course, but is quasi-simple) has a complex irreducible character of degree $3$.

Comment: See \S 8.5 in W. Feit, The current situation in the theory of finite simple groups, Actes. Cobgr. Internat. Me\ath. Nice 1970, vol.1 Gauthhier-Villars, Paris, 1971, 55-93.

Comment: There is also a book by H.F. Blichfeldt, "Finite Collineation Groups", U. of Chicago Press, 1917, that contains a chapter of degree 3 case. It's not  hard to read; except that the terminology is old... I have an e-copy and can email you a link to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on how much group theory you want to use. If $G$ is such a simple group and $\chi$ is a faithful complex irreducible character of degree $3$, then a Theorem of Feit and Thompson proves that $|G|$ is not divisible by any prime $p > 7$. It is easy to check (since $Z(G)$ contains no element of order $3$), that $G$ has Abelian Sylow $3$-subgroups. Hence for any $x \in G$ of order $3$, we have ${\rm gcd}([G:C_{G}(x)],\chi(1)) = 1$. By a result of Burnside, we have $\chi(x) = 0$ since $G$ is simple. It then easily follows that $|G|$ is not divisible by $9$. It also follows that a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$ is self-centralizing ( from this, it already follows from  1962(?) theorem of Feit and Thompson in Nagoya J. Math, that $G \cong {\rm PSL}(2,7)$ or $A_{5}$. For, more generally, we see that $\chi(g) = 0 $ whenever $g$ centralizes a Sylow $3$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, and then $|C_{G}(P)|$ divides $3$). A representation theoretic proof in this special case can be sketched  as follows (using a few tricks not available to Blichfeldt):

Now $G$ has cyclic Sylow $7$-subgroups for otherwise, $G$ contains a element of order $7$ with eigenvalues $1,\omega, \omega^{-1}$, where $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}}$, which contradicts a theorem of Blichfeldt ( as $\chi$ must be primitive ( otherwise $G$ would be solvable)). Consideration of reduction (mod $7$) shows that the Sylow $7$-subgroup of $G$ has order at most $7$. Furthermore, if $7$ divides $|G|$, it follows from Burnside's normal $p$-complement theorem that a Sylow $7$-normalizer must have order $21$.

Since $G$ has no element of order $35$, it follows from another theorem of Blichfeldt that $|G|$ can't be divisible by $35$ ( since otherwise, $\chi$ is neither $5$-rational nor $7$-rational, and would contain an element of order $35$. But consideration of reduction (mod $5$) shows that no element of order $5$ can commute with any element of order $7$).

If $G$ contains an element of order $5$ with only two eigenvalues then an argument of Blichfeldt shows that ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ as a subgroups, and contains an element of order $6$ with eigenvalues $1, \alpha, {\bar \alpha}$ for a primitive $6$-th root of unity, which ( by another of his results) contradicts the primitivity of $\chi$. It follows that $G$ has cyclic Sylow $5$-subgroups which have order at most $5$ on consideration of reduction (mod $5$).

It now follows that $|G|$ has the form $2^{a}.3.5$  or $2^{b}.3.7$ for integers $a,b$. Similarly to the argument for $7$, we may conclude that a Sylow $5$-normalizer has order $10$ if $5$ divides $|G|$. This gives $a \equiv 2$ (mod $4$) or $b \equiv 3$ (mod $6$) by Sylow's theorem.
 A Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ has an Abelian normal subgroup $A$ of index  dividing $2$, and a 1965 Theorem of Brauer shows that $|A|$ divides $4$ so $|S| \leq 8$ and we do get $|G| = 60$ or $168$.

Comment: Thanks vm Geoff. It will take me some time to go through your proof but it is extremely precious ! May I just ask: when you mention reduction, do you refer to the use of modular representations or something else ?

Comment: Yes, reduction mod p refers to realising the representation over a local ring and looking at images mod the unique maximal of that ring in the standard manner.

Comment: @ Geoff. Do you have a preferred reference for some examples of reduction? Also, how do you prove that a Sylow $-$normalizer must have order 21. All I have is $C_G(P<N)G(P)$ by Burnside and $[N_G(P):C_G(P)]\in \{2,3,6\}$ by the N/C lemma.

Comment: The Sylow $7$-subgroup is self-centralizing  by a subtle argument which I think originates with Brauer. Take a prime $q \neq p$ and suppose $x \in C_{G}(P)$ is an element of order $q$. Reduce the representation (mod $q$), and note that $P$ is diagonalizable, and since a generator of $P$ has three different eigenvalues, anything which centralizes $p$ is daigonalizable too. Hence $x$ acts trivially (mod $q$), so $x \in O_{q}(G) = 1$. Alsao $N_{G}(P)$ can't be a Frobenius group of order $42$. I have still left out a few details.

Comment: As for reduction $(mod $p$)$, I like Curtis and Reiner 1962 ( Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras) but all books on modular representation theory cover it.

Comment: Thanks very much Geoff for the explanation. I would not have found this one by myself :-) This glimpse at modular representation theory shows it is very powerful !

Comment: An indication of the power of modular representation theory is given by the fact that finite primitive subgroups of ${\rm GL}(4,\mathbb{C})$ were determined by Blichfeldt in about 1917, while the primitive subgroups of ${\rm GL}(5,\mathbb{C})$ were determined by Brauer in 1965.

Comment: Hi Geoff, I may ask again for your help as I am really stuck on this one: Now $G$ has cyclic Sylow $7$-subgroups for otherwise, $G$ contains a element of order $7$ with eigenvalues $1,\omega, \omega^{-1}$, where $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}}$, I could show that the $7-$Sylow is abelian but that's all.

Comment: It would be easier to look up the standard proof as I only gave a sketch: Sylow $7$ $S$ is Abelian of exponent (at most) $7$ ( the exponent $7$ comes form looking at reduction (mod $7$)). If $S$ contains an elementary Abelian subgroup $A$ of order $49$, then $A$ may be assumed to consist of all diagonal matrices of order $7$ determinant $1$ so contains an element of order $7$ with eigenvalues as stated, which contradicts a result of Blichfeldt ( see L. Dornhoff, Part A) for example).

Comment: Thanks very much once again. It is very clear and very helpful :-)

Answer (score -1):

A comprehensive report on groups possessing a faithful irreducible character of small degree is contained in Walter Feit's report `The current situation in the theory of finite simple groups, Actes Congr. Internat. Math. Nice 1970, vol. 1 Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1971, 55-93.'

Comment: How does this answer the question ? This is at best a comment.

Comment: That report by Feit contains a number of inaccuracies.